# PBI RLS and lookup tables

Tags: filter, powerbi, lookup-tables, row-level-security

I reckon that this is a recurrent theme, but unfortunately I can't seem to make it work for my usecase, so apologies for the redundancy...

I have the following data model and relationships in PBI:
the contracts table is what I used to create two lookup tables (lookup client and lookup office) a one-directional many to one relationship for each.

[image]

I have RLS applied on the contracts table which is working fine, but I can't figure out how to have it applied on the lookup tables as well and not hamper performance.

I tried changing to a bidirectional relationship but obviously it did not work for the other lookup table and it seems highly unrecommended as well.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Why? If it's just to filter the slicers on your report, do this instead: https://www.sqlbi.com/articles/syncing-slicers-in-power-bi/